# How to change decoding to utf-8?

Tags: python, utf-8, python-2.x, xlrd

I am reading data from an Excel file (from given cells). I've set the encoding to utf-8 to read also the accentuated letters.

```
for file in glob.glob('N:\SAJAT_MAPPAK\IGYULAVICS\SargaTabla\Egyadat\*.xls'):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(file, formatting_info=True, encoding_override="utf-8")
    sheets = book.sheet_names()
    first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)
    print first_sheet.name
    rows, cols = first_sheet.nrows, first_sheet.ncols
    print "Number of rows: %s   Number of cols: %s" % (rows, cols)
    hidneve = first_sheet.cell(7, 9)
    print hidneve
```

It works well for the sheet names, like: `Törzs adatok (1. oldal)` for the first sheet.
But doesn't work for `hidneve`, because it is still like: `u'R\xe1kospatak utca az M3 fkl. \xfat felett'` instead of `Rákospatak utca az M3 fkl. út felett`.

Comment: Perhaps the console or terminal you are printing to doesn't support utf-8.

Comment: Do not use Python 2 for Unicode text. It is possible (but more complex): Python 3 solved the issue (all is Unicode internally) more than 10 years ago. There are just few months remaining for Python2, so it is difficult to find somebody who can answer (by remembering how we did long time ago).

Comment: I think you're seeing the `repr`esentation form (note the quotes and the `u` prefix) because `hidneve` is a list or some other container, not a plain string. Compare `print u'Törzs'` vs. `print [u'Törzs']` and maybe `print repr(u'Törzs')`. That said, Giacomo's comment is right too.